# iOS CAGradientLayer is not working with some colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have used below code to set gradient background color of my view.

```
 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:44/255 green:58/255 blue:76/255 alpha:1].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:17/255 green:22/255 blue:30/255 alpha:1].CGColor];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

But its not working. Screen will appear with black color. But when I try to set color like below

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

then it working fine.I am getting correct output. Can anyone help me to fine why gradient color is not working with UIColor colorWithRed function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:202.0/255.0 green:107.0/255.0 blue:122.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:192.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:120.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

For the original poster's code to work, he just has to divide each color component by 255.0 instead of 255, if not the result is truncated to an int.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:44/255.0 green:58/255.0 blue:76/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:17/255.0 green:22/255.0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Alternatively, make the dividend a float value:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:44.0/255 green:58.0/255 blue:76.0/255 alpha:1].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:17.0/255 green:22.0/255 blue:30.0/255 alpha:1].CGColor];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Or the most easy to follow solution, make both numbers in the division a float value:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 green:58.0/255.0 blue:76.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:17.0/255.0 green:22.0/255.0 blue:30.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this!

```
 -(CAGradientLayer *)makeGradientView :(UIColor *)topColor BottomColor:(UIColor *)bottomColor withFrame:(CGRect )rect
{
    CAGradientLayer *theViewGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    NSArray *gradientLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0], nil];
    theViewGradient.locations = gradientLocations;
    theViewGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)topColor.CGColor,(id)bottomColor.CGColor,(id)bottomColor.CGColor,(id)bottomColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
    theViewGradient.frame = rect;
    theViewGradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(1,1);
    theViewGradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0,0.1);
    return theViewGradient;
}
```

And you can use like this!

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
CAGradientLayer *theViewGradient = [self makeGradientView:[UIColor colorWithRed:189/255.0 green:227/255.0 blue:106/255.0 alpha:0.5] BottomColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:13/255.0 green:184/255.0 blue:196/255.0 alpha:0.5] withFrame:self.view.bounds];
[_mainView.layer addSublayer:theViewGradient];
```